# centos 8 kernel 4.18 patches

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, kernel, patch

Centos 8 uses 4.18 linux kernel. But the venila Linux kernel 4.18 is heavily patched in centos. from where to get the detail patches which is applied on top of 4.18 for centos 8 stream? I am specifically looking for icelake processor support patches.

Comment: Example 'Changelog', 4.18.0-373.el8 : https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/8-stream/baseos/x86_64/Packages/kernel-core-4.18.0-373.el8.x86_64.html . ... Source https://vault.centos.org/8-stream/BaseOS/Source/SPackages/ → →  kernel-4.18.0-373.el8.src.rpm https://vault.centos.org/8-stream/BaseOS/Source/SPackages/kernel-4.18.0-373.el8.src.rpm

Comment: kernel-4.18.0-373.el8.src.rpm : `$ grep -in icelake kernel.spec | wc -l` : 34 lines about **Icelake support**. -